# Pilot light out - propane tank empty

Tags: hvac

I have an unattended house which I kept the gas (propane) furnace running at 62 degrees to help keep pipes from freezing this winter.  I ran out of gas and the furnace shut down.  Can I have the tank filled a day or so before I get to the house to light the pilot?  Will the gas keep running if the pilot is not lit? filling the house with gas.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure _any_ gas would come out?  Modern appliances use a thermocouple to cut gas flow if the pilot light goes out.

Comment: @JPhi1618 yes and that is the reason why you muss typically press a button to lit the pilot. Pressing the button is necessary so that gas comes out. Otherwise, no gas can come out unless it is at ignition temperature. Although I don't feel I know enough about gas to tell someone "yes, it's fine"

Comment: it's supposed to be ok. it's probably ok. I don't think anyone here wants to go out on a limb if your valve is corroded or faulty though, so that's about as re-assuring as we'll get.

Comment: My advise would be to advise the propane filler to shut the valve feeding the house off at the tank before they refill.  advise them since they are refilling an empty tank it is a safety precaution and they should be happy to comply.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it but @Tyson advice to have them turn off the service valve is the best for safety, + should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll flesh out my comment into an answer.  If this is a newer furnace, no gas will flow if the pilot light is out.  I don't have much experience with furnaces, so for all I know, they were always made like this.

I do have experience with water heaters.  When you light the pilot on your furnace, do you have to hold a button down for a long time while lighting to get the pilot to stay lit?  Or do you just have to turn on the gas and light it?

If you have to hold down a button, then the appliance has the safety feature that will cut off the gas when the pilot goes out.  Holding down the button bypasses the safety valve so some gas will come out and allow you to light the pilot.  Once lit the safety is disengaged.

Answer (score 0):

That depends what there are for appliances and how old (or old-fashioned) they are.

Anything without a "standing pilot" (pilot light that's lit all the time) should be fine unless it's actually "on."

The most common example of a standing pilot WITHOUT a "safety shutoff" (thermocouple valve to kill the gas if the pilot goes out) would be an older kitchen range. Newer ones with spark ignition have no pilots (and expensive, failure-prone glow igniters in the oven, usually.) Water-heaters and furnace/boilers have had pilot safety valves for quite a long time.

*As an aside, 55°F would have been a more economical "keep from freezing" temperature, but draining the pipes and putting non-toxic antifreeze in the toilets and sink traps is cheaper yet on heat (we used to do it every fall at "camp.")*

Answer (score -2):

No worries! No pilot. No Gas. No hazard.

Comment: i spoke too soon...

Comment: Hi, Paul. Could you add a few sentences to this? Because otherwise it really doesn't improve on the other answers.

Comment: The safeties necessary to preclude hazardous situations for the above equipment in the above situation have been built-in for many many years.